# Natbib to skip citation order in list of figures

Tags: xetex, natbib

I have citations in my figures caption, which gets numbered as [1], and the citation in chapter 1 gets numbered as [4].

I want the citation in chapter 1 to be numbered as [1] without removing the citation in the caption.

I know one of the solutions is using `\caption[<Figure title>]{<Figure title> \cite{<Source>}}`, but I would prefer not to do so many edits to my document.

Any other easy way to do this would be greatly appreciated.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{iiit_thesis}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

% ----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lmodern,soul}
\usepackage[sort, numbers, comma, square]{natbib}
% \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%% TITLE PAGE
\input{titlePage.tex}

%% COPYRIGHT PAGE
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thesisdedication}{{\large Copyright \copyright~~ 2023\\}{\large All Rights Reserved\\}}
\thesisdedicationpage

%%% DEDICATION PAGE
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thesisdedication}{\large To FAMILY \& FRIENDS}
\thesisdedicationpage

\mastersthesis
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%--------------------------------------------------------

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}
\input{introduction.tex}
```

Introduction.tex

```
\section{Introduction}
Hello\cite{somecitation}

\subsubsection{mysubsection}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[trim=10 5 10 2, clip, width=0.30\linewidth]{LaTex/figures/fig1122.eps}
\end{minipage}
\caption{caption has citation\cite{<somecitation2>})}
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by using `\usepackage{notoccite}`